# Array Contains Performance

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I have a program which works with arrays and at some point I have to check if a lsit of values are inside an array, the function that does this takes about 70% of the program CPU time, so I was wondering if there's a way to do this more efficiently.

These are my functions:

```
private static int[] GenerateRow(int length, Random RNG)
    {
        int[] row = InitalizeRow(length);
        int index = 0;
        while (!AreAllNumbersGenerated(row))
        {
            int value = RNG.Next(0, length);
            if (!RowContains(row, value))
            {
                row[index] = value;
                index++;
            }
        }
        return row;
    }  

    private static bool AreAllNumbersGenerated(int[] row)
    {           
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)            
           if(!RowContains(row, i))
                return false;           
        return true;
    }

    private static bool RowContains(int[] row, int value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
            if (row[i] == value)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

All the work is by `AreAllNumbersGenerated()`, then by `RowContains()` and finally by this line:

`if (row[i] == value)`

That this functions take most of the time is normal, since they do heavy work, but I wanted to know if there's a better way to do this.

EDIT:

```
   private static int[] InitalizeRow(int length)
    {
        int[] row = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            row[i] = -1;
        return row;
    }
```

Comment: If you're generating "everything" anyway, why don't you just use a shuffle?

Comment: I don't know what that is, I'll look it up.

Comment: Can you paste the InitializeRow function code as well? Thanks.

Comment: @Eru It just sets all numbers to -1, because 0 would be a problem.

Comment: There are definitely better ways to do what `GenerateRow` method does. But is the question about that method? Or `AreAllNumbersGenerated`? Is the later used for something else in your program?

Comment: 1) Listen to harold. If you're going to generate all numbers anyway, then generate them and perform a shuffle. 2) Absent that, use a HashSet<int> to get lookups in O(1) time. Has this number already been generated? *Look in the hashset.* 3) But really, shuffle. Even with fast lookups provided by the HashSet, you're eventually going to spend so much time colliding with already-generated values.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I might be the odd one out here, but I was assuming the `InitializeRow` function is a dummy for some array population mechanism that *doesn't* insert all numbers. For this situation you can't use a shuffle as a substitute. Otherwise I don't understand what the point of this code is.

Comment: May want to have a read here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61338/generate-random-numbers-without-repetitions

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Also, if the point of this code really is to just generate a random array, you should walk the array and sample without substitution from all numbers, rather than shuffling, since this is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a method, thanks to **@sous2817** comment, that works perfectly for me.

```
public static int[] GetRandomNumbers(int count, Random RNG)
    {
        HashSet<int> randomNumbers = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            while (!randomNumbers.Add(RNG.Next(count))) ;
        return randomNumbers.ToArray();
    }
```

This works ~10 times faster then what I was doing and works nicely with the rest of my program.I needed the code to be "linear" so other solutions mess my program.  Anyway, thanks to everyone that helped :)

Comment: you can simplify the for loop `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) while (!randomNumbers.Add(RNG.Next(count))) ;` to `while (randomNumbers.Count < count && !randomNumbers.Add(RNG.Next(count)));`

Answer (score 3):

You're wasting a lot of work by doing a linear scan for every number throughout the array. What you should instead do is walk the array once and start observing the last number you've seen. If you see any gaps, return false. If you reach the end of the array, return true. This is O(N) instead of O(N^2) like you have it now.

Like so:

```
public static bool AreAllNumbersGenerated(int[] row)
{
    var last = 0;
    return row.Aggregate(true, (l, r) => l && r == last++);
}
```

You can make some additional optimizations that won't affect your big-O complexity, e.g. using a proper loop and early-exiting.

EDIT: I'm assuming here that you're expecting the items to occur sequentially. If this isn't the case, you can easily convert the array to a structure with ~O(1) lookups in O(N), then do the check in O(N) as well. For large input, this is still better than your O(N^2) approach above

Like so:

```
public static bool AreAllNumbersGenerated2(int[] row)
{
    var available = row.ToDictionary(x => x);
    return Enumerable.Range(0, row.Length).All(i => available.ContainsKey(i));
}
```

EDIT: From what I'm seeing in the comments it looks like the goal of this code is to populate an array with a contiguous sequence of numbers in a random order. I didn't realize that was the goal, and if that is the case, shuffling is certainly better than reattempting to generate over and over. But what is even better than generating the array then shuffling (again, for sufficiently large input) is to simply generate the array by assigning each number to a randomly sampled index without substitution. Not as easy to LINQ out, but you can figure it out.

Comment: How do you even sample without replacement in the first place? Of course we could shuffle and array of contiguous integers again, but that's already the result.

Comment: @harold You start by putting all the indices in a constant time lookup and initialize a counter to zero. While the counter < array length, randomly select and index and remove it from the lookup, and put the counter's value in that index of the array. Increment the counter. This is overall O(N).

Comment: Ok that would work, but that sounds worse than shuffling.

Answer (score 2):

As others in the comments have pointed out, the most efficient way to do this is to generate an array with the values you want and shuffle it:

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] arr, Random r)
{
    for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        int j = r.Next(i + 1);
        T tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }
}

public static int[] Generate(int length, Random r)
{
    var arr = new int[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    Shuffle(arr, r);
    return arr;
}
```

then

```
var arr = Generate(10, new Random());
foreach (int i in arr) { Console.WriteLine(i); }
```

Comment: I tried that and the performance is the same as some other method I found, but it fits what I want to do more.

Comment: +1, but this is going to produce a biased shuffle. You can turn this into a fair Fisher-Yates shuffle by substituting `r.Next(arr.Length)` with `r.Next(i)` I think.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of shuffle, you can generate the possible values in a list and take values at random positions. That way you can start using the items even before the whole row is generated:

```
    IEnumerable<int> RandomRange(int count) {
        var random = new Random();
        var list = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) list[i] = i;

        while (count > 0) {
            var i = random.Next(count);
            yield return list[i] ;
            list[i] = list[--count];
        }
    }
```

sample use:

```
foreach(var item in RandomRange(10))
    // ...
```

Comment: This turns what would otherwise be an O(n) operation into an O(n^2) operation.

Comment: @Servy how do you get O(n^2)? taking an item from a list at random position is O(1) so it would be O(n) to generate the list + O(n) to take all the items from it.

Comment: `O(n) to take all the items from it` there is your false assumption.  It's O(n) to take *one* item, using your code; doing that n times makes it O(n^2).

Comment: You can't RemoveAt(i) then, you have to swap with the last item and then remove the last position. Also there's no point in being lazy if you're going to generate the entire thing anyway. And you can do the same thing with a shuffle, if you really want.

Comment: @harold There's no reason to remove the last item, really.  It's easier to just leave it.  Doing that also means you don't need to copy the entire collection as you don't need a list.

Comment: @Servy and then we have re-derived the shuffle :)

Comment: @Servy thanks, seems linear now. I did not consider the memory copy after `RemoveAt(i)`.