# Faster Scramble Millions Numbers

Tags: arrays, vb.net, algorithm, performance, shuffle

I need to scramble HUGE integer arrays (from 1,000,000 to 80,000,000 elements).

These arrays are sequential created (1 to n step 1) and I need to ensure that no one sequential number is lost - and because of it I cannot create "random numbers" arrays.

So, I create them using a single FOR-NEXT (it takes very low time, about 2ms) and I utilize the Fisher-Yates-Durnstenfeld shuffle algorithm, as follows.

First I create the array:

```
 dim Huge(0 to 80,000,000) as Integer
 For x as integer = 1 to 79,999,999
     Huge(x) = x
 Next
```

It takes really few miliseconds to be created...

After, I scramble the numbers:

```
    Shuffle(Huge)
```

where Shuffle is **a routine called in a Parallel/Multitasking environment**. Because of this, I need to LOCK the RANDOM function (to provide good entropy in swaping values and locations) utilized in Fisher-Yates-Durstenfeld routine :

## The Fisher-Yates Shuffle

```vb
Friend Sub Shuffle(ByRef Buffer As Integer())
  For max As Integer = Buffer.Length - 1 To 1 Step -1
      ExtractRandomItem(Buffer, max)
  Next
End Sub

Friend Sub ExtractRandomItem(ByRef buffer As Integer(), max As Integer)
  Dim random As Integer = GetRandomNumber(max + 1)
  If random = max Then
     random -= 1
  End If

  Dim temp As Integer = buffer(max)
  buffer(max) = buffer(random)
  buffer(random) = temp
End Sub

Friend Function GetRandomNumber(max As Integer) As Integer
  Dim _random As New System.Random
  SyncLock _random
      Return _random.Next(1,max)
  End SyncLock
End Function
```

### My problem

This shuffle routine is pretty good to scramble randomly the array, but, if it takes only 2ms to scramble 8192 elements, for **24,000,000 elements it takes 32 seconds** - too much time for my needs.

**Do you know any way to enhance this process and make it faster?**

**Or do you know another non-deterministic shuffle algorithm to work faster than that I have?**

Note: *I had already tried PARALLEL.FOR and I had no expressive gain anyway (just few miliseconds in fact)*.

And I don't really need "random-like" shuffle but just a non-deterministic  ordering.

Thanks for any help

**UPDATE**

Due to relevant comments of Jdweng and Hans, I feel it's interesting to make an appointment:

- The routine works with 2 arrays at same time (an input and an output) and each of them may have until 32 mega-elements (> 33 millions each one), which cause .NET to allocate almost 1Gb of RAM. It's not my choice, but the system requirement, sometimes.
- So, I need avoid to create a new array to substitute the SWAP operation to an  in -> out operation...

**UPDATE II**

Some guys had recommended good practices, but they are not eligible to solve the problem. Let me discuss each of them:

- **Using different arrays**: this procedure may save some clocks-by-operation avoiding swap (3 ops) for using move between array A and B. But it will require to double the RAM request (two identical matrices). It's not an option using huge matrix over NET-Framework memory allocation schema (which require free consecutive blocks of memory).
- **Using MergedShuffle algorithm**: it seems to be the most desirable solution but I'm affraid of having the shuffle separated "by pieces of the matrix", since this schema works on pieces of the matrix based on their middle points. I need to study it deeper to understand the whole process.
- **Using parallel on pieces of the main array**: it is not an option since the shuffle will comply only the imposed range - in other words, I won't have the last elements shuffled with the initial elements of the array. It can be seen as a kind of deterministic schema (not an option).

Comment: Possibly useful / duplicate - [Parallel Computing - Shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266968/parallel-computing-shuffle).

Comment: Fastest method is not to do a swap.  The swap take 3 moves.  If you create a new array you can just move a number from 1st array to new array which is one move.  So the fast algorithm for X numbers is follows : get random number from 1 to N = R.  Move R to new array.  Then take last item in old array and move to position R.   Then X - 1.  Repeat until X = 0.  You now have a two move shuffle instead of a three move shuffle.

Comment: Avoiding the synclock to protect the System.Random instance is easy enough, just give each thread its own instance.  The real problem is ExtractRandomItem(), it has a threading-race bug.  Note how two threads could arrive at the same `random` value, when they both write to the same array index one of the values will be lost.  Fisher-Yates is fundamentally sequential, and partitioning is not an option, parallelizing it is just not possible.  Google "mergeshuffle" for a possible alternative.

Comment: Thank you both Jdweng and Hans - you wrote really relevant comments. I will edit the message for more info about the routines.

Comment: so each thread using only part of the range is not an option?

Comment: How are the results used/issued?  Picking random items from the pool wont prevent dupes if that is an issue.  Depending on that, you might be able to build the pool incrementally

Comment: @Slai, in fact the MergeShuffle algorithm recommended by Hans works in that idea. But anyway, I need to balance these cost of RAM (using replicated pieces of matrix or the entire matrix) vs performance. But to utilize, for instance, Task.Run() with pieces of matrix although guess to be a very fast option, the time (and RAM) cost to run these may impact on the gotten benefits.

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm sorry but I couldn't understand exactly your point of view. I will need all results, I mean, the entire matrix values. I cannot discard any value and value-repetition (or lack) is not allowed.

Comment: I dont get `value-repetition (or lack) is not allowed` can values repeat or not?  If they cannot, you must discard used values or else picking a random one even from a very large pool could result in a duplicate.  In that case, I wonder why the time to shuffle is an issue since you would only shuffle once (unless the pool is refilled).

Comment: @Plutonix, neither repetitions nor "jumps/lacks" are allowed. I don't need a random-array but shuffle a sequential one. The Fisher-Yates consider a really randomic space of distribution, since for every swap, the algorithm picks a new "distance" (random). That's what I need: the most non-deterministic shuffled array of sequential numbers.

Comment: Yes, I am very well aware of the difference between an random pool and a shuffled one.  I am asking about *usage* of the pool values.  If you just pick random values, they could repeat.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the question and the problems, but if the numbers are used only once, they can be used as soon as the "shuffle" starts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235803/array-contains-performance/39237785#39237785. The total time is a bit more, but no need to wait for the shuffle to finish.

Comment: @Plutonix, yes, now I see that using random at parallel even letting a decreased MAX to avoid repetitions over the same matrix index, I'm still in risk to get same values within the defined range - and because being in parallel, even MAX can be repeated...

Comment: @Slai, I'm sorry but I didn't understand...  I can utilize the matrix only when all values are shuffled to avoid any repetition during its usage. I meam, if I shuffle the 3rd element and utilize it right now, at the Nth swap I can get again that 3rd element against a new other element. Problem. The values can be utilized just a single time.

Comment: I am asking about things 2-3 steps back from the implementation posted (@Slai too apparently).  I dont get why the time to shuffle is an issue since the pool ought to be shuffled only once.

Comment: `if I shuffle the 3rd element and utilize it right now, at the Nth swap I can get again that 3rd element against ` thats not true with a proper FY shuffle.  each element is moved into the final position exactly once.  Many naive implementations get this wrong

Comment: @Plutonix, I must avoid a deterministic jump which I will get if using a single pool. See the code: I decrement the "max" value from matrix and in the pool is done between any of the remaining values, to get the most "random" distribution. I mean: the same "3rd" element CAN (and it's desirable) to be changed with any other and more than one time.

Comment: @Slai, the recommended answer (#39237785) select a random matrix - that's not my case. My array is a sequential one (it must be!) and I must ensure that all numbers from 1 to n are there...  but shuffled.

Comment: Once the pool of values is shuffled it stays shuffled and the contents are still 1 to n.  It only needs to be shuffled once ever.  How values are ***used*** or issued from the pool via threads would seem to be the real issue.  You wont tell us how they are used though

Comment: @Plutonix, my problem is not after the shuffle, but the shuffle routine itself. If it is utilized, for instance, to shuffle 33 million elements, it takes too much time. I guess the problem may be focused in the "SyncLock" of random (and other not seen before problems of doing random in parallel).

Comment: So is the point of the **Parallel/Multitasking environment** solely to solve the shuffle time problem or will the pool of values be used from different threads?  We just dont have a complete picture

Comment: @Plutonix, the problem is focused only in how to shuffle the huge array in less than 2 seconds - even using a mono or multithreaded schema. The multithreaded schema to shuffle 33 mega elements is not quite fast as I supposed to be using the FISHER-YATES algorithm. The problem may reside in the number of randoms pooled OR in the lock of the random function to prevent colisions in parallel usage.

Comment: This is so confusing, and you have changed the posted problem several times.

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something - but why do you need to synclock a local variable?

Comment: You might not be able to do this in your situation, but moving the declaration of random from local variable to global seems to result in a huge performance increase. On my pc, your code rakes 47s, but after moving the declaration of _random to global, it takes a about 4.25s to scramble 24 million elements

Comment: Also, rather than calling a function to generate the random number. changing the line to `    Dim random As Integer = _random.Next(1, max + 1)` bring further performance increases - 3.1s to scramble

Comment: @DavidBS - why does the array have to be "shuffled"?  If all you are doing is getting a random element then it shouldn't need to be shuffled at all.

Comment: @dbasnett, I don't need a random array, which can loose some numbers of a sequential order. I need to shuffle an array of variable size,  but *always* made by sequential numbers.

Comment: @DavidWilson, this routine will be called in a parallel environment (the original array may contain billions numbers) and the SYNCLOCK is to avoid any colision - but as righly pontined for Hans Passant, it may also create undesirable repetitions.

Comment: @DavidWilson, if I don't initialize "a new Random" I will always have the same numbers since the seed will be the same, due to characteristics of Random function. Because of it I initialize everytime the function. I need also the most random distribution I can get, so, shuffle the array with a single "step" (provided by a single random number) is not a choice.

Comment: @DavidBS - if I have an array of sequential numbers I can access them randomly.  Also, the problem seems to have changed again, "(the original array may contain billions numbers)".

Comment: @dbasnett, you're focusing in the amount of numbers and it's *not* the focus of the problem. In resume: I need to shuffle millions of integers in a random way (not a "step" way) in the less possible time. It can be done in mono or multhreaded way but, this routine will be called from other parallel routine - in other words, it may be prepared to this.

Comment: @dbasnett, my problem is **not focused** in how to access the numbers...

Comment: @DavidBS - all that was stated as usage of the array was GetRandomNumber.  My point was that if that is all the usage the the array does not need to be shuffled.  If it isn't the only usage then show it.

Comment: @dbasnett, focus on the problem - the random shuffle of huge arrays. How it can be used after this is not relevant...

Comment: @DavidBS - what?  The usage is absolutely relevant.  A clear statement of the problem(millions or billions) is also relevant.  There are solutions that might satisfy your needs but those are unclear.  You are stating a solution instead of stating the problem.  For example, when you do access the array how responsive does that need to be?

Comment: @DavidBS fair enough, but the randomization of `Random` uses a time based seed at the tick level. I ran your code with a slight modification to record the random numbers generated and they were very non random. For example in my first run, the first several numbers were .. 35786663
35786662
35786662
35786661
35786661
35786660
35786660
35786659
35786659
35786659
35786658
35786658
35786657
35786657
35786656. .net randomization is problematic when repeatedly run on short time scales.

Comment: You could declare _random as a global and in the `Shuffle` sub add the following line `_random = New Random`. That way you would get a new seed every time `Shuffle` was called. That should neutralize the problems with very high frequency randomization.
`

Comment: @DavidWilson, that's exactly what I'm doing at GetRandomNumbers function and, the fact of putting the New Random declaration in Global declares (and using an array of 32,000,000 elements) didn´t give me a reasonable time savings. But thank you. And I did the same test like you and I got 13432339, 30794731, 16963307, 19381238, 6632825 - a reasonable random - not perfect at all, I agree, but not the same results you got...  Anyway, I don't need *real randoms* but a honest non-deterministic result.

Comment: Supid computers - why cant they be consistent? ;-)

Comment: I presume you also removed the new Random  declaration from the GetRandomnumber function as well tho?

Comment: @DavidWilson, no, I don't ...  :)

Comment: That would be why you didnt get the speed difference

Comment: You're right @DavidWilson - I didn't feel a lack of randomness but I really got no expressive time savings...  Remeber that this routine is called from others in a multhreaded way. The problem is really focused (I guess) in the SyncLock...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your poor performance is because you're creating a new random number generator for every random number.  I got a 7x speed increase by only creating one.  I also merged all the code into a single function to maximize the optimization from .net.  The final result is just under 10x faster (117 seconds to 12 for 80,000,000 items on my 32-bit Win7 virtual machine).

```
Friend Sub Shuffle(ByRef Buffer As Integer())
    Dim _random As New System.Random
    For max As Integer = Buffer.Length - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Dim random As Integer = _random.Next(1, max)
        Dim temp As Integer = Buffer(max)
        Buffer(max) = Buffer(random)
        Buffer(random) = temp
    Next
End Sub
```

Note a lock is not needed for the random number generator because each call to Shuffle has its own copy and isn't shared across threads.

70% of the time is spent reading the value from Buffer(random).  This is because it's likely not in the CPU cache and has to hit main memory whereas reading Buffer(max) is only .5% because it's being read sequentially descending and the CPU can pre-read it into cache.  20% is in calculating the random number so with a faster generator, you can save a little more time but not much.

The big win would be an algorithm that didn't randomly access the array for every element.  I followed the advice of Hans Passant in the question comments and googled [MergeShuffle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.03167.pdf).  It seems to be just such an algorithm (multiple sequential accesses instead of a random single pass).  And in addition to allowing partitioning, it does not require more RAM.

I prototyped it and I saw a 20% speed up with 80M items switching to Fisher-Yates at 2.5M items.

Comment: Thank you Tony Lee, I will test it tomorrow.
Anyway, I agree with you in a search of an algorithm to avoid a "random call" at every step to ensure the desirable (and non-predictive) distribution.